# How can I complete an instruction using variables?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to make a function that changes the colors of the console when called, with the ones I choose. I don't want to write 3 instructions every time I do that, so that's why I want it to be in a function.

So far I've done something similar to this:

```
public static void WindowColor(string Background, string Foreground)
{
    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Background;
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Foreground;
    Console.Clear();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    WindowColor("DarkCyan","White");
}
```

where `ConsoleColor.Background` and `ConsoleColor.Foreground` I want to be replaced with `ConsoleColor.DarkCyan` and `ConsoleColor.White`, as I called in `WindowColor("DarkCyan","White");`.

But I get this error:

> 'ConsoleColor' does not contain a definition for 'Background'.

Now I get the fact that `Background` in `ConsoleColor.Background` is not seen as a variable, but rather as a part of the instruction, but the question is: How can I make `Background` or `Foreground` be seen as a completion of the instruction in the form of a variable?

Comment: Why would you not use `WindowColor(ConsoleColor.DarkCyan, ConsoleColor.White)` instead? Or use `using static` in C# 6 and `WindowColor(DarkCyan, White)`? (And change the type of each parameter to `ConsoleColor`, ideally renaming it to be idiomatic at the same time.) Do you *want* to remove compile-time checking?

Comment: I didn't know I can do that, I just started using C#. But it solved my problems. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, you would just use the correct type of parameter instead of string:

```
public static void WindowColor(ConsoleColor background, ConsoleColor foreground)
{
    Console.BackgroundColor = background;
    Console.ForegroundColor = foreground;
    Console.Clear();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    WindowColor(ConsoleColor.DarkCyan, ConsoleColor.White);
}
```

If you insist on it having strings as parameters, you will have to parse them:

```
public static void WindowColor(string Background, string Foreground)
{
    Console.BackgroundColor = (ConsoleColor) Enum.Parse(typeof(ConsoleColor), Background, true);
    Console.ForegroundColor = (ConsoleColor) Enum.Parse(typeof(ConsoleColor), Foreground, true);
    Console.Clear();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    WindowColor("DarkCyan","White");
}
```

Comment: I just found out I can do that. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Just using `Parse` is dangerous. If the string cannot be parsed, this will throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

`Console.ForegroundColor` and `Console.BackgroundColor` are of type [ConsoleColor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolecolor(v=vs.110).aspx), not string. If you want your function to work, you will need to change your parameter types to ConsoleColor:

```
public static void WindowColor(ConsoleColor Background, ConsoleColor Foreground)
{
    Console.BackgroundColor = Background;
    Console.ForegroundColor = Foreground;
    Console.Clear();
}
```

Alternatively, you could keep it as a string, then try and parse the string as an enum value:

```
public static void WindowColor(string Background, string Foreground)
{
    ConsoleColor b, f;

    if (   Enum.TryParse(Background, out b)
        && Enum.TryParse(Foreground, out f))
    {
        Console.BackgroundColor = b;
        Console.ForegroundColor = f;
        Console.Clear();
    }
}
```